# Wordpress API v1.1 turning https into http in img srcset attributes

Tags: wordpress, srcset, wordpress-rest-api

Here's a summary of the situation:

- I have blog posts created on a Wordpress blog hosted on wordpress.com. They work fine and all embedded images render when I preview the post in edit mode. When I inspect the post preview, the img src and srcset attributes use https as expected.
- I retrieve the posts via the public REST API to display on my company's site (for SEO purposes).
- Along the way, the img tags' srcset attribute links are losing their ’s’ and  being rendered as http (as opposed to https).
- The images are failing to load because people access our website via https and many browsers won’t load insecure http content on such a site.

I have seen somewhat similar questions on StackOverflow, but I believe mine is unique for two reasons: first, I'm using the Wordpress REST API, and second, the blog is hosted on wordpress.com, therefore I can't install custom plugins or edit the underlying PHP.

**Update:** As of October 25th, 2016, our blog is working correctly again. It would appear that Wordpress has quietly fixed this issue on their side.

Comment: Any chance you're using the WP Force SSL plugin?

Comment: @GregBurkett No, I'm not. It's not even available to activate on a blog hosted at wordpress.com as far as I can tell.

Comment: Ah, I see -- can you post your API call / code in your question please? (Remove any API keys for security)

Comment: @GregBurkett It would be a GET request to an address like this one (I'm inserting spaces because StackOverflow is truncating the full address otherwise): https:// public-api.wordpress.com/ rest/v1.1/sites/my-site.wordpress.com/posts/

Comment: At this point the only thing I can think to try would be to change themes to a default and try pulling the data. But beyond that, this really seems like a bug in the API itself. Although, since you're pulling the post's content via API and displaying on another site, it'd be easy enough to do a search and replace on the content that comes through and replace any src='http://wordpress-domain-name.com' with src='https://wordpress-domain-name.com'. It's a workaround rather than a solution, but it might be your only option right now.

Comment: @GregBurkett Thank you so much for taking time on this. That's more or less the conclusion we came to as well—it really appears to be the API's fault and there's not much we can do about that part. I think we'll probably end up implementing some kind of search & replace solution as you've suggested.